# Use custom E-Mail Server with SAP SuccessFactors

Tags: sap-successfactors

How is it possible to use a custom mailserver for sending E-Mails from SAP SuccessFactors? Every System Mail should be send via custom server. I found this in a [KBA](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2688533):

**SuccessFactors mail notifications can integrate externally with a customer, e.g. can you relay mail through a customers’  mail servers?**

*Yes this is possible. We can forward outgoig emails to customer's own SMTP server(s). We only need:
the condition (recipient domain);
the customer's SMTP server's IP and port;
SMTP auth user and password if needed.*

I can't find any description how to set this up. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a Ticket to SAP via https://support.sap.com/